# c# update graphics canvas after resizing panel

Tags: c#, winforms, canvas, graphics, panel

Must be a simple question but can't find the answer, must be because I'm quiet new to c#.

I've got a windows form with in this a panel, say 500x500 pixels. 
When form is initalized, it also creates a graphics g.

Then after selecting a colour I can draw on the panel with pen p.

This all works fine.

But then, I resize the panel by clicking a button giving it 500 pixels to the left (or down to it).

Now, altough I see the extra 500 pixel, when drawing it still only draws within the 500x500 (probably cause this was the panel1 size when initialized by g = panel1.creategraphics().

So how do I update this region to draw on? I've tried to do it with clip en clipbounds but this seems to be something else (couldn't get that working either).

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Don't use `CreateGraphics()`. Use the Paint event of the Panel (but better use a PictureBox or a flat Label) to draw on its surface. The `PaintEventArgs` of the Paint event provide the `e.Graphics` object you need.

Comment: Why? is this not simply possible with just mouse_up mouse_down events? Cause that's how I got the other stuff working now and this Paint Event Method gives me all kind of new different problems. it's not that I don't want to solve all these new problems but is gonna take time, while I expect there to be an easier method to just update the 'drawing canvas area or something'?

Comment: No, it's not possible (if you want to build something that works, that is). You have to use the `e.Graphics` object provided by the `PaintEventArgs`. You'll find a host of examples around. If you find some *code snippets* that use `CreateGraphics()`, skip them without a second thought. Test it, if it doesn't come out right for some reason, post your code, along with a good description of what, in your view, it doesn't do the way it should. Since you haven't, you should also read: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Well, if not possible, how come i did it then? Seems like moving the Graphics to the mouse-move event did the trick, see code below

Comment: Use the Paint event. The Paint event receive the Graphics object created when a Control receives a `WM_PAINT` message. That's the Graphics object you need. Just minimize and restore your Form to see why. Plus, using the proper way to handle the Graphics of a Control, your code doesn't actually change, it's simply moved to another event handler. You really need to learn this, if you want your app to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
    ArrayList listofpoints;
    bool moving = false;

    int panelhoogte = 500;
    int panelbreedte = 500;
    Color def = Color.Black;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listofpoints = new ArrayList();
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox p = (PictureBox)sender;
        def = p.BackColor; 
    }

    private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Point punt = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
        listofpoints.Add(punt);
        moving = true;
        panel1.Cursor = Cursors.Cross;
    }

    private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics();
        g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        Point punten = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
        Pen penceel = new Pen(def, 5);
        penceel.StartCap = penceel.EndCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.Round;
        if (moving && listofpoints.Count > 1)
        {
            g.DrawLine(penceel, (Point)listofpoints[listofpoints.Count - 1], punten);
            listofpoints.Add(punten);
        }
    }

    private void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        moving = false;
        panel1.Cursor = Cursors.Default; 
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panelhoogte = panelhoogte + 500;
        panel1.Height = panelhoogte;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panelbreedte = panelbreedte + 500;
        panel1.Width = panelbreedte;
    }
```